# How do I access pointer to Structure instead of its elements from iterator in STL list

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I have a structure of the following form

```
class   THistory
{
/* */
 public:
    UInt32      userId;
    UInt32      trip;

};
```

List looks like follows

```
THistory hist2;
std::list<THistory> temp;
std::list<THistory>::iterator it = temp.begin();

hist2.userId=userId;//passed by some function storing in tempory structure
hist2.trip=trip;//passed by some function storing in tempory structure
temp.push_back(hist2);//Pusing into list
```

My problem is I can access

```
it->userId and 
it->trip
```

but HOW do I access entire structure. I need to pass entire structure pointer to some other function rather than individual elements. Also, is the above approach correct of using temporary sturcture to populate the elements of structure before pushing into list.

UPDATING based on answers:
I pass the iterator as follows

```
getLocations(&*it);
```

definition:

```
getLocations( THistory *hist){
    ////
}
```

My code builds but, it crashes at runtime

"Error: Iterator is deferencable"  I steped inside the function, it hits list function call internal to library and crashes here

```
reference operator*() const
    {   // return designated value
    return ((reference)**(_Mybase *)this);
    }
```

I am getting confused. Hope it is not silly error

Comment: _"but HOW do I access entire structure. "_ `(*it)`

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: `std::list<THistory>::iterator it = temp.begin();` - Um... looking at your code, *nothing* is in the list at that point, right? That iterator won't magically start pointing to what you inserted *after* you acquired it.

Comment: yes, I missed that... thnx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the structure, you use the dereference operator `*` on the iterator. And to get a pointer to the structure you use the address-of operator `&`.

So e.g. `&*it`

***But*** (and this is very important) you should first check if the iterator is actually referencing a valid element in the list. The way you show the code in your example, the list is empty and `temp.begin()` will return the `temp.end()` iterator, which shouldn't be dereferenced.

However I fail to see why you need a pointer, unless the function you need to call was written by someone else. If you have written, or can rewrite the function, then change it to use a reference (or a reference to a constant) to the structure, and you don't need to use pointers. You really should avoid pointers as much as you can in C++.

---

As for adding elements to the list, then what you show should work just fine. But if you add a constructor taking the required arguments then you don't need a temporary variable, and could to e.g.

```
temp.push_back(THistory(userId, trip));
```

Comment: @user437777 You *did* read the paragraph starting with ***"But (and this is very important) ..."***?